# Triangulation of polygon

Tags: c, geometry, triangulation

Im trying to triangulate a polygon for use in a 3d model. When i try using the ear method on a polygon with points as dotted below, i get triangles where the red lines are. Since there are no other points inside these triangles this is probably correct. But i want it to triangulate the area inside the black lines only. Anyone know of any algorithms that will do this?

[image]

Comment: You can cut the figure into convex parts and triangulate these. Gets messy for large complicated figures, though.

Comment: Has your triangulation any constraints (Delaunay?) or do you have any time constraints? Otherwise the answer will be rather broad.

Comment: There are no constraints, the model is generated once, so time is not a big issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many algorithms to triangulate a polygon that do not need partitioning into monotone polygons first.  One is described in my textbook [*Computational Geometry in C*](http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/books/compgeom.html), which has code associated with it that can be freely downloaded from that link (in C or in Java).
You must first have the points in order corresponding to a boundary traversal.  My code assumes counterclockwise, but of course that is easy to change.  See also the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation).  Perhaps that is your problem, that you don't have the boundary points consistently organized?

Comment: Love your book Joseph, have a couple of editions of it sitting on the shelf behind me.  Sits in pride of place among Edelsbrunner, Shamos & Perparata, and Hjelle & Daehlen.  A real must have for anyone working with TINs.

Comment: @Shane: Thanks for the kind words! :-)

Answer (score 2):

The usual approach would be to split your simple polygon into monotone polygon using trapezoid decomposition and then triangulate the monotone polygons.
The first part can be achieved with a sweep line algorithm. And speed-ups are possible with the right data-structure (e.g. doubly connected edge list). The best description of this, that I know, can be found in [Computational Geometry](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3642096816). [This](http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~suri/cs235/Triangulation.pdf) and [this](http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/Compgeometry/MyCG/PolyPart/polyPartition.htm) also seem helpful.

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia suggest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_polygon) that you break the polygon up into monotone polygons.   You check that the polygon is not concave by simply checking for all angles being less than 180 degrees - any corners which has a angle of over 180 is concave, and you need to break it at that corner.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use C++, you can use [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org) and in particular the example given [here](https://lists-sop.inria.fr/sympa/arc/cgal-discuss/2011-11/msg00150.html) that can triangulate a set of non-intersected polygons. This example works only if you already know the black segments.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the EarClipping algorithm, not the Delaunay. See the following white paper: http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/TriangulationByEarClipping.pdf